# how to change the shape of the button from rounded rectangle to circle using animation

Tags: android

I have a rounded rectangle button in my activity. Once I click the button, it should slightly compress/shrink (height of the button should not change) and it should change to a circle shape. How can I achieve this using the anim folder in XML?

Currently my code is:

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:fillAfter="true">
    <scale
        android:duration="400"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:toXScale="0.1"
        android:toYScale="1" />
    <set>
        <alpha
            android:duration="400"
            android:fromAlpha="1"
            android:toAlpha="0" />
    </set>
</set>
```

Comment: https://github.com/dmytrodanylyk/android-morphing-button

Comment: hai @rajesh kushvaha thanks for your help but, my button is in rounded rectangle shape not in rectangle shape. I want to change the shape of a button from rounded rectangle to circle using anim file I dont want to use any other third party library. It will be good if you can help me in that way.

Comment: grab a code from library do not add as dependency :)

Comment: ok @rajesh kushvaha thank you so much

Comment: hai @rajesh kushvaha I cant able to grab the code from the library, can you please give me the simple example which will show the rounded rectangle button(not rectangle) converting to circle while clicking on the same. once it will convert to circle it should move to second activity I am unable to acheive the same. please help me

Comment: hope this code will work 4u, i have tested nd working fine for me!

Comment: did you find solution for this question?

Answer (score 6):

> Create MorphingButton class paste below code into;

```
public class MorphingButton extends Button {

private Padding mPadding;
private int mHeight;
private int mWidth;
private int mColor;
private int mCornerRadius;
private int mStrokeWidth;
private int mStrokeColor;

protected boolean mAnimationInProgress;

private StrokeGradientDrawable mDrawableNormal;
private StrokeGradientDrawable mDrawablePressed;

public MorphingButton(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initView();
}

public MorphingButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    initView();
}

public MorphingButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    initView();
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    if (mHeight == 0 && mWidth == 0 && w != 0 && h != 0) {
        mHeight = getHeight();
        mWidth = getWidth();
    }
}

public StrokeGradientDrawable getDrawableNormal() {
    return mDrawableNormal;
}

public void morph(@NonNull Params params) {
    if (!mAnimationInProgress) {

        mDrawablePressed.setColor(params.colorPressed);
        mDrawablePressed.setCornerRadius(params.cornerRadius);
        mDrawablePressed.setStrokeColor(params.strokeColor);
        mDrawablePressed.setStrokeWidth(params.strokeWidth);

        if (params.duration == 0) {
            morphWithoutAnimation(params);
        } else {
            morphWithAnimation(params);
        }

        mColor = params.color;
        mCornerRadius = params.cornerRadius;
        mStrokeWidth = params.strokeWidth;
        mStrokeColor = params.strokeColor;
    }
}

private void morphWithAnimation(@NonNull final Params params) {
    mAnimationInProgress = true;
    setText(null);
    setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, 0);
    setPadding(mPadding.left, mPadding.top, mPadding.right, mPadding.bottom);

    MorphingAnimation.Params animationParams = MorphingAnimation.Params.create(this)
            .color(mColor, params.color)
            .cornerRadius(mCornerRadius, params.cornerRadius)
            .strokeWidth(mStrokeWidth, params.strokeWidth)
            .strokeColor(mStrokeColor, params.strokeColor)
            .height(getHeight(), params.height)
            .width(getWidth(), params.width)
            .duration(params.duration)
            .listener(new MorphingAnimation.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void onAnimationEnd() {
                    finalizeMorphing(params);
                }
            });

    MorphingAnimation animation = new MorphingAnimation(animationParams);
    animation.start();
}

private void morphWithoutAnimation(@NonNull Params params) {
    mDrawableNormal.setColor(params.color);
    mDrawableNormal.setCornerRadius(params.cornerRadius);
    mDrawableNormal.setStrokeColor(params.strokeColor);
    mDrawableNormal.setStrokeWidth(params.strokeWidth);

    if(params.width != 0 && params.height !=0) {
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = getLayoutParams();
        layoutParams.width = params.width;
        layoutParams.height = params.height;
        setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
    }

    finalizeMorphing(params);
}

private void finalizeMorphing(@NonNull Params params) {
    mAnimationInProgress = false;

    if (params.icon != 0 && params.text != null) {
        setIconLeft(params.icon);
        setText(params.text);
    } else if (params.icon != 0) {
        setIcon(params.icon);
    } else if(params.text != null) {
        setText(params.text);
    }

    if (params.animationListener != null) {
        params.animationListener.onAnimationEnd();
    }
}

public void blockTouch() {
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return true;
        }
    });
}

public void unblockTouch() {
    setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            return false;
        }
    });
}

private void initView() {
    mPadding = new Padding();
    mPadding.left = getPaddingLeft();
    mPadding.right = getPaddingRight();
    mPadding.top = getPaddingTop();
    mPadding.bottom = getPaddingBottom();

    Resources resources = getResources();
    int cornerRadius = (int) resources.getDimension(R.dimen._10sdp);
    int primaryColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorAccent);
    int secondaryColor = resources.getColor(R.color.colorPrimary);

    StateListDrawable background = new StateListDrawable();
    mDrawableNormal = createDrawable(primaryColor, cornerRadius, 0);
    mDrawablePressed = createDrawable(secondaryColor, cornerRadius, 0);

    mColor = primaryColor;
    mStrokeColor = primaryColor;
    mCornerRadius = cornerRadius;

    background.addState(new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed}, mDrawablePressed.getGradientDrawable());
    background.addState(StateSet.WILD_CARD, mDrawableNormal.getGradientDrawable());

    setBackgroundCompat(background);
}

private StrokeGradientDrawable createDrawable(int color, int cornerRadius, int strokeWidth) {
    StrokeGradientDrawable drawable = new StrokeGradientDrawable(new GradientDrawable());
    drawable.getGradientDrawable().setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
    drawable.setColor(color);
    drawable.setCornerRadius(cornerRadius);
    drawable.setStrokeColor(color);
    drawable.setStrokeWidth(strokeWidth);

    return drawable;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void setBackgroundCompat(@Nullable Drawable drawable) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        setBackgroundDrawable(drawable);
    } else {
        setBackground(drawable);
    }
}

public void setIcon(@DrawableRes final int icon) {
    // post is necessary, to make sure getWidth() doesn't return 0
    post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Drawable drawable = getResources().getDrawable(icon);
            int padding = (getWidth() / 2) - (drawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / 2);
            setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, 0, 0, 0);
            setPadding(padding, 0, 0, 0);
        }
    });
}

public void setIconLeft(@DrawableRes int icon) {
    setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(icon, 0, 0, 0);
}

private class Padding {
    public int left;
    public int right;
    public int top;
    public int bottom;
}

public static class Params {
    private int cornerRadius;
    private int width;
    private int height;
    private int color;
    private int colorPressed;
    private int duration;
    private int icon;
    private int strokeWidth;
    private int strokeColor;
    private String text;
    private MorphingAnimation.Listener animationListener;

    private Params() {

    }

    public static Params create() {
        return new Params();
    }

    public Params text(@NonNull String text) {
        this.text = text;
        return this;
    }

    public Params icon(@DrawableRes int icon) {
        this.icon = icon;
        return this;
    }

    public Params cornerRadius(int cornerRadius) {
        this.cornerRadius = cornerRadius;
        return this;
    }

    public Params width(int width) {
        this.width = width;
        return this;
    }

    public Params height(int height) {
        this.height = height;
        return this;
    }

    public Params color(int color) {
        this.color = color;
        return this;
    }

    public Params colorPressed(int colorPressed) {
        this.colorPressed = colorPressed;
        return this;
    }

    public Params duration(int duration) {
        this.duration = duration;
        return this;
    }

    public Params strokeWidth(int strokeWidth) {
        this.strokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        return this;
    }

    public Params strokeColor(int strokeColor) {
        this.strokeColor = strokeColor;
        return this;
    }

    public Params animationListener(MorphingAnimation.Listener animationListener) {
        this.animationListener = animationListener;
        return this;
    }
}
public static class MorphingAnimation {

    public interface Listener {
        void onAnimationEnd();
    }

    public static class Params {

        private float fromCornerRadius;
        private float toCornerRadius;

        private int fromHeight;
        private int toHeight;

        private int fromWidth;
        private int toWidth;

        private int fromColor;
        private int toColor;

        private int duration;

        private int fromStrokeWidth;
        private int toStrokeWidth;

        private int fromStrokeColor;
        private int toStrokeColor;

        private MorphingButton button;
        private MorphingAnimation.Listener animationListener;

        private Params(@NonNull MorphingButton button) {
            this.button = button;
        }

        public static Params create(@NonNull MorphingButton button) {
            return new Params(button);
        }

        public Params duration(int duration) {
            this.duration = duration;
            return this;
        }

        public Params listener(@NonNull MorphingAnimation.Listener animationListener) {
            this.animationListener = animationListener;
            return this;
        }

        public Params color(int fromColor, int toColor) {
            this.fromColor = fromColor;
            this.toColor = toColor;
            return this;
        }

        public Params cornerRadius(int fromCornerRadius, int toCornerRadius) {
            this.fromCornerRadius = fromCornerRadius;
            this.toCornerRadius = toCornerRadius;
            return this;
        }

        public Params height(int fromHeight, int toHeight) {
            this.fromHeight = fromHeight;
            this.toHeight = toHeight;
            return this;
        }

        public Params width(int fromWidth, int toWidth) {
            this.fromWidth = fromWidth;
            this.toWidth = toWidth;
            return this;
        }

        public Params strokeWidth(int fromStrokeWidth, int toStrokeWidth) {
            this.fromStrokeWidth = fromStrokeWidth;
            this.toStrokeWidth = toStrokeWidth;
            return this;
        }

        public Params strokeColor(int fromStrokeColor, int toStrokeColor) {
            this.fromStrokeColor = fromStrokeColor;
            this.toStrokeColor = toStrokeColor;
            return this;
        }

    }

    private Params mParams;

    public MorphingAnimation(@NonNull Params params) {
        mParams = params;
    }

    public void start() {
        StrokeGradientDrawable background = mParams.button.getDrawableNormal();

        ObjectAnimator cornerAnimation =
                ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(background, "cornerRadius", mParams.fromCornerRadius, mParams.toCornerRadius);

        ObjectAnimator strokeWidthAnimation =
                ObjectAnimator.ofInt(background, "strokeWidth", mParams.fromStrokeWidth, mParams.toStrokeWidth);

        ObjectAnimator strokeColorAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(background, "strokeColor", mParams.fromStrokeColor, mParams.toStrokeColor);
        strokeColorAnimation.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());

        ObjectAnimator bgColorAnimation = ObjectAnimator.ofInt(background, "color", mParams.fromColor, mParams.toColor);
        bgColorAnimation.setEvaluator(new ArgbEvaluator());

        ValueAnimator heightAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(mParams.fromHeight, mParams.toHeight);
        heightAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mParams.button.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.height = val;
                mParams.button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });

        ValueAnimator widthAnimation = ValueAnimator.ofInt(mParams.fromWidth, mParams.toWidth);
        widthAnimation.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                int val = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                ViewGroup.LayoutParams layoutParams = mParams.button.getLayoutParams();
                layoutParams.width = val;
                mParams.button.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
            }
        });

        AnimatorSet animatorSet = new AnimatorSet();
        animatorSet.setDuration(mParams.duration);
        animatorSet.playTogether(strokeWidthAnimation, strokeColorAnimation, cornerAnimation, bgColorAnimation,
                heightAnimation, widthAnimation);
        animatorSet.addListener(new AnimatorListenerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animator animation) {
                if (mParams.animationListener != null) {
                    mParams.animationListener.onAnimationEnd();
                }
            }
        });
        animatorSet.start();
    }

}
public class StrokeGradientDrawable {

    private int mStrokeWidth;
    private int mStrokeColor;

    private GradientDrawable mGradientDrawable;
    private float mRadius;
    private int mColor;

    public StrokeGradientDrawable(GradientDrawable drawable) {
        mGradientDrawable = drawable;
    }

    public int getStrokeWidth() {
        return mStrokeWidth;
    }

    public void setStrokeWidth(int strokeWidth) {
        mStrokeWidth = strokeWidth;
        mGradientDrawable.setStroke(strokeWidth, getStrokeColor());
    }

    public int getStrokeColor() {
        return mStrokeColor;
    }

    public void setStrokeColor(int strokeColor) {
        mStrokeColor = strokeColor;
        mGradientDrawable.setStroke(getStrokeWidth(), strokeColor);
    }

    public void setCornerRadius(float radius) {
        mRadius = radius;
        mGradientDrawable.setCornerRadius(radius);
    }

    public void setColor(int color) {
        mColor = color;
        mGradientDrawable.setColor(color);
    }

    public int getColor() {
        return mColor;
    }

    public float getRadius() {
        return mRadius;
    }

    public GradientDrawable getGradientDrawable() {
        return mGradientDrawable;
    }
}
}
```

> Add this widget in your layout.xml

```
<com.test.widgets.MorphingButton
        android:id="@+id/btnDone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="DONE"/>
```

> In Activity to animate view onButtonClick

```
write below code inside `MorphingButton` onClick
MorphingButton.Params circle = MorphingButton.Params.create()//To animate in circle from rect-round
                    .duration(500)
                    .cornerRadius((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._100sdp))
                    .width((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._56sdp))
                    .height((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._56sdp))
                    .color(Color.BLUE) // normal state color
                    .colorPressed(Color.GREEN) // pressed state color
                    .icon(R.drawable.ic_loader); // icon
            btnDone.morph(circle);

//To animate from circle to rect-round to this demo purpose
            btnDone.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MorphingButton.Params square = MorphingButton.Params.create()
                            .duration(500)
                            .cornerRadius((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._100sdp))
                            .width((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._100sdp))
                            .height((int) getResources().getDimension(R.dimen._56sdp))
                            .color(Color.BLUE) // normal state color
                            .colorPressed(Color.GREEN) // pressed state color
                            .icon(R.drawable.ic_loader) // icon
                            .text("DONE");
                    btnDone.morph(square);
                }
            }, 5000);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. exactly what I needed. U can add the preview here so people get to know what the end result would look like